# How to fix Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() with array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, setstate

I have an array `tranches: [{ start: moment().format("HH:mm"), end: moment().format("HH:mm") }]` and when I set the value of the `tranches[0].start` without `setState` I get :

```
Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()
```

My code is :

```
handleAjouter = (start, end, date) => {
    this.state.tranches[0].start = start;
    this.state.tranches[0].end = end;
    this.setState({
      tranches: this.state.tranches
    });
  }
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone the `tranches[0]` object instead of mutating it, which you can achieve concisely with object spread:

```
handleAjouter = (start, end, date) => {
  const [firstTranch] = this.state.tranches;
  this.setState({
    tranches: [
      { ...firstTranch, start, end },
      ...tranches.slice(1)  // needed if the array can contain more than one item
    ]
  });
}
```

If you need to insert the changed tranch at a specific index, then clone the array and insert the tranch:

```
const tranches = this.state.tranches.slice();
tranches[index] = { ...tranches[index], someOtherProp: 'foo' };
```

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance, and what about when I have `this.state.tranches[selectedIndex] = {
      ...this.state.tranches[selectedIndex],
      [startOrEnd]: textValue
    };`

Comment: Slice the whole array first, and then you can reassign the element at the desired index

Comment: I try const `tranches = this.state.tranches.slice();
    tranches[selectedIndex] = { ...tranches[selectedIndex], [startOrEnd]: textValue };
    this.setState({
      tranches:this.state.tranches
    });` But it doesn't working.

Comment: You set the new state to exactly the same thing as the old state. Call `setState` with the *new* `tranches` array instead. `this.setState({ tranches });`